# When do I need "Host permission" in my chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I thought I can't use `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` on, say, google.com, if I don't have `"*://*.google.com/"` among `permissions` in `manifest.json`. But turns out I can. Probably, due to `activeTab` permission?

I've deleted the extension, loaded unpacked again to make sure it's not some kind of cache and it still works. So, what exactly does this scary "host permission" do? In which case would I need it?

Comment: This is exactly the purpose of `activeTab`, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab).